# LoL player needs help configuring DotA 2 quick cast controls

Tags: dota-2

I have my keys in LoL like this:

```
Shift does not queue commands.
Shift-key = quick cast
Control-key = quick self cast
```

Since I can configure my keys like this in both LoL and HotS, I'm sure that if I don't play DotA with these, it will start confusing me in the other two games.

Last time I checked (a while ago, admittedly) I could not bind the control key in this way since it was reserved. Is there some way I can get around this? I can play on either OSX or Windows 10, so third-party keyboard modifiers on either platform are a possibility.

I tried asking on the Steam forum, but they just threw a bunch of insults at me.

Comment: Hmm I dont have dota 2 installed right now, so i can't check. But you could remap your control key with the help of an autohotkey script. Very easy to write and you can toggle it on/off with a hotkey aswell.

Comment: So this hotkey thing would intercept control, and send it as something else, fooling dota?

Comment: Yes, you could set quickcasting in dota on a unused key like "U" for example. In your autohotkey script your could map Control => U, so everytime you press control, U gets pressed and your quickcast.

Comment: @PaulErlenmeyer thanks a lot, I have come up with something that works based on this comment. Makes a mess of normal typing though. ;)

Comment: Doing that kind of stuff for a long time since many games don't allow you to change all or certain hotkeys. Yeah the writing gets messed up. Therefore I recommend to have a on/off toggle button aswell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer I came up with was to use [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/), a keyboard remapping app.

The config looks like this:

```
{
  "title": "DotA 2 quick cast modifiers",
  "rules": [
    {
      "description": "Map <shift-key> combinations to quick-cast keys.",
      "manipulators": [
        {
          "type": "basic",
          "from": {
            "key_code": "q",
            "modifiers": {
              "mandatory": [
                "left_shift"
              ]
            }
          },
          "to": [
            {
              "key_code": "t"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": "basic",
          "from": {
            "key_code": "w",
            "modifiers": {
              "mandatory": [
                "left_shift"
              ]
            }
          },
          "to": [
            {
              "key_code": "y"
            }
          ]
        },
```

This remaps <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>q</kbd> to <kbd>t</kbd>, and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> to <kbd>y</kbd>. In DotA 2, I have <kbd>t</kbd> set to quick-cast the normal <kbd>q</kbd> spell, and <kbd>y</kbd> to quick-cast the normal <kbd>w</kbd> spell, etc. Add more in that comma-seperated list.